# When is a wonderful compactification a toric variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, toric-varieties, hyperplane-arrangements

Given a (projective) hyperplane arrangement $\mathcal{A}$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$, in which we assume the intersection of all hyperplanes is $0$, and a building set $G$, De Concini and Procesi define the wonderful compactification $Y_{\mathcal{A},G}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ as the closure of its image in
$$\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{C}^n)\times\prod_{X\in G}\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{C}^n/X).$$

It is known, see for example [Section 5](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.3519), that there is a minimal projective toric variety $X_{\mathcal{A},G}$ containing $Y_{\mathcal{A},G}$. In some cases, say for $\mathcal{A}$ the braid arrangement and $G$ the minimal building set, it is known that the wonderful compactification itself is toric.

Is there a general condition on $\mathcal{A}$ and $G$ capturing when the associated wonderful compactification is a toric variety?